# Jobs RSS feed does not show all results in real time

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs, rss

I contacted Stack Overflow support a few weeks ago and they said I should ask my question here:

There is an issue with the jobs RSS feed that I noticed several times. For example, the 15 May I updated the [RSS feed for remote jobs](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?location=remote) and on the 27 May I updated it again and I saw that unread jobs from the [12 May](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/254867/junior-ruby-on-rails-developer-iubenda?a=1ntpVA1jJdHW) and [13 May](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/246840/senior-3d-ar-vr-visualization-developer-falkbuilt?a=1kMvQYmuS6ac) were added in my RSS client (Thunderbird).

These jobs should have been added to the list on the 15 May when I updated the RSS feed but they were missing.

Do you know where the problem comes from and does Stack Overflow plan to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We've been looking into this report, and we can’t replicate the issue you described. For now, I've marked this question as non-repro. Let me know if you see it again.

For your information: we don't do any special processing with the feed. It simply returns the last 1000 published jobs. The backdating of jobs in the feed may just be a quirk of your RSS client (in this case, Thunderbird).

Comment: I can confirm that the issue happens again. I am using several RSS feeds and the issue happens only with StackOverflow Jobs so it looks like it is not a Thunderbird bug.